# Can enabling static_framework in podspec break existing apps?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I'm maintaining a library written in Swift and distributed via CocoaPods. Since version 1.4.0 cocoapods introduced the `static_framework=true` setting the podspec file. Recently, a user of the library asked me if I could add `static_framework=true` setting to the podspec file of the library.

Naturally, I'm worried that if I do that it may introduce problems for existing library users. Can anything go wrong with enabling `static_framework=true`? Are there any possible negative side effect for my library users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are two downsides of using `static_framework`:

- Any CocoaPods that depend upon a `static_framework` CocoaPod will
  also need to be static frameworks.
- Static Frameworks won't be shared
  across extensions leading to possible code bloat. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html).

And two upsides of using `static_framework`:

- Allow static library and binary static [vendored_framework](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks)
  dependencies.
- Libraries get linked at build time instead of load time.